# Canvas is not defined for simple chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to put a simple chart on my website. I have this code:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
canvas.width = parent.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = parent.offsetHeight;

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  options: {
      legend: {
      display: false
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  },
  data: {
    labels: [3,4],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Test 01',
        data: [1,2],
      }
    ]
  }
});
</script>
<div id="parent">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

However it returns me the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: canvas is not defined
    at mytest3.html:47
```

I've tried moving the canvas above and below the script but it doesn't make a difference. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: pretty hard to reference an element before it exists. Where is `canvas` defined?

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to get the canvas like
`var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart')`

Comment: Thank you for this. When i do this though it gives me the error ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
    at mytest3.html:44```

Comment: Ah I moved the html above and it works now thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the canvas variable before you use it. Add the following:

```
<script>
//Add the following line
var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Comment: And move the script

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the script AFTER the element exists. You need to define canvas....

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<!-- Need to put canvas before the script -->
<div id="parent">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");  // <-- need to define canvas
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
canvas.width = parent.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = parent.offsetHeight;

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  options: {
      legend: {
      display: false
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  },
  data: {
    labels: [3,4],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Test 01',
        data: [1,2],
      }
    ]
  }
});
</script>
```